# can Firebase be used to verify phone number excluding signin process

Tags: android, firebase

hey i wanted to verify phone number in sign up process in my android app.Can this be done using Firebase. Also i wanted to skip the signin process which occurs after verification.

Comment: Ya u can do it by using the firebase Authenticcation

Comment: after verification user is added in firebase console. i want to skip that process.

Comment: Answer below. But it sounds a bit like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish by verifying the phone number? And why is the creation of a user profile keeping you from that?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase got the functionality once the app on device is verified then you can enter this code to check 
`if ( user == null)`
Where is of Firebase User type and then transfer to authentication Java file using intent,
otherwise bypass the user to main conent.

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

There is no way to verify a phone number with Firebase Authentication without creating a user profile. Verifying the phone number of the user means that you're identifying the user.